# Rewarding the person who helps catch a thief, Islamic or not?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, reward

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

In a scenario where a Muslim has something of his stolen, and another Muslim brother comes along and informs him of the thief and his whereabouts and gives a testimony of him witnessing the robbery which is later proved to be accurate and the theif is caught.

In this case, can the owner of the stolen goods reward the brother who helped him, with a portion of that stolen goods as a token of thanks?

Is this considered imitating the kufr or unislamic in anyway or can it be understood to be encouraged?

Comment: There is  **[جعالة](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/21239/rulings-on-jaaalah-price-offered)** that is established from [Quran 12:72](https://quran.com/12/72).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell based on this scenario, all that is occurring is that the owner is offering a reward to the individual for his help. As far as I know there is nothing  sacrilegious about doing so.